# The instance of entity type cannot be tracked with a composite primary key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm getting this error, but I can't seem to find a proper resolution.

> The instance of entity type 'Assignment' cannot be tracked because
> another instance with the same key value for {'OwnerUserId'} is
> already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that
> only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Functionally all I'm trying to do is insert some records with a composite primary key.  Basically I just need to assign users to each other.  I'm telling the context (afaik) to not do tracking, yet the error still seems to happen.

```
        using (var context = new MyDbContext())
        {
            context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
                 
            //Get students with no assignments
            var missingAssignments = model.Students.Where(x => x.AssignedToRead.Count < 2);
            foreach (var s in missingAssignments)
            {
                var need = 2 - s.AssignedToRead.Count();
                List<Guid> assigned = new List<Guid>();
                assigned.AddRange(s.AssignedToRead.Select(x => x.UserId));

                try
                {
                    for (var i = 0; i < need; i++)
                    {
                        //Get a random reader (who's not them)
                        var shuffle = model.Students.Where(x => x.UserId != s.UserId).Where(x => !assigned.Contains(x.UserId)).ToList();
                        shuffle.Shuffle();
                        var rando = shuffle.FirstOrDefault();

                        var newAssignment = new Assignment() {
                            OwnerUserId = s.UserId,
                            ReaderUserId = rando.UserId
                        };

                        assigned.Add(rando.UserId);

                        context.Add(newAssignment);
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }catch(Exception ex)
                {
                   //Handle
                }
            }
        }
```

I've validated I'm not inserting duplicate records (like 2 objects with the same PKs)

Is the problem in the mapping maybe?

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Assignment>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.OwnerUserId, e.ReaderUserId });

            entity.ToTable("assignments");

            entity.Property(e => e.OwnerUserId).HasColumnName("ownerUserId");
            entity.Property(e => e.ReaderUserId).HasColumnName("readerUserId");

            entity.Property(e => e.ModifiedDate)
                .HasColumnName("modifiedDate")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("(getdate())");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Owner)
                .WithOne()
                .HasPrincipalKey<Assignment>(d => d.OwnerUserId)
                .HasForeignKey<AspnetUsers>(d => d.UserId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_users_owner");


            entity.HasOne(d => d.Reader)
                .WithOne()
                .HasPrincipalKey<Assignment>(d => d.ReaderUserId)
                .HasForeignKey<AspnetUsers>(d => d.UserId)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_users_reader");
        });
```

I don't understand why it would be tracking when I tell it not to

**EDIT** It appears the issue is with my Navigation Property mapping on the context? If i remove that entirely the Insert works fine, and I still have functioning Nav Properties on the object... I'm so confused, I thought it had to be told what to do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe any entity added using `Add` will be tracked, the tracking behaviour is for entities that are queried from the DB. Does the error happen on the first instance you add, or on the second, or later?

I suspect the issue is probably with the HasOne.WithOne mapping between Assignment and User. I think this should be a HasOne.WithMany as a One-to-One typically defaults to being between PKs. (Though /w EF Core I believe you can nominate a non-PK 1-to-1) This mapping may be overruling the PK definition or otherwise adding a unique requirement that the tracking is considering. One User can have many assignments, but each assignment has one owner.

Another thing to check: In your entity class definition for Assignment, do you happen to have any `[Key]` attributes defined that might be tripping up the EF mapping? Your modelBuilder key mapping otherwise looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the HasOne.WithOne Mapping should change to HasOne.WithMany. I'm solve my problem after reading your answer. Save my day.